# Integer Solutions to $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n$ = number

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

The question is how many solutions to the equation $a+b+c+d+e+f+g=20$ are there if all terms are nonnegative integers and $a+b+c=10$?

To answer this, would I just take the number of solutions to $a+b+c=10$ and multiply it by the number of solutions to $d+e+f+g=10$?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Using [this resource](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) it is $$\binom{10 + [3-1]}{3-1} \times \binom{10 + [4-1]}{4-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is basically correct.
To figure out the number of solutions to $a+b+c=10$ and $d+e+f+g=10$, you can use the method of 'stars and bars'.